# Confused about commit hash in tsd.json

Tags: angularjs, typescript

[Link to history of angular-ui-router d.ts file using the commit hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg74A.jpg)

I have the following in my tsd.json file
``

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "93bae1bb4c887c1375a4c1f0c3bb849ff06b8ac6"
    },
    "angularjs/angular.d.ts": {
      "commit": "93bae1bb4c887c1375a4c1f0c3bb849ff06b8ac6"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-route.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6a6ad7068a177c0d7a8a20830626cb63277191c5"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-animate.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6a6ad7068a177c0d7a8a20830626cb63277191c5"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-sanitize.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6a6ad7068a177c0d7a8a20830626cb63277191c5"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts": {
      "commit": "1984ea435fe9e93a012d50db7773db58ae5d494b"
    },
    "angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts": {
      "commit": "d1f6bde13f2209be42e86c3686761e8bfcbb50a5"
    },
    "angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts": {
      "commit": "93bae1bb4c887c1375a4c1f0c3bb849ff06b8ac6"
    }
  }
}
```

``
How does the commit hash work? I tried to see the angular-ui-router type definition file with the commit hash like this..
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/93bae1bb4c887c1375a4c1f0c3bb849ff06b8ac6
but that  did not lead me the angular-ui-router definition file with the hash defined above. see the image in history

So every time I do an tsd install, do I get the same commit version every time ?

If I want to upgrade to a new version, I would have to run tsd update angular-ui-router, I guess?

Sorry for these questions but I did search a lot without getting a concrete answer.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has is the hash of the latest commit for the complete DefinitelyTyped repository.

You can read more about this here: [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/226)

You will get other hashes every time you update your definitions, for example with tsd update command.